# Question on convergence of a formula for the Dirichlet eta function $\eta(s)=(1-2^{1-s})\,\zeta(s)$

Tags: number-theory, convergence-divergence, riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series

> **Question**: Is it true that formula (1) below for $\eta(s)$ converges for $\Re(s)>-m$ as $N\to\infty$ and if so, is formula (1) somehow related to the derivation of formula (2) below for $\eta(s)$ which is globally convergent?

**(1)** $\quad\eta_{\,m,N}(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}+\frac{1}{2^m}\sum\limits_{n=1}^m\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m-n+1}\binom{m}{m-n+1-i}\right)\frac{(-1)^{N+n-1}}{(N+n)^s}\,,\\$ $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad Re(s)>-m?\land N\to\infty$

**(2)** $\quad\eta(s)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\,\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{(k+1)^s}\quad$(see [Dirichlet eta function: Numerical Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function#Numerical_algorithms))

---

The following figures illustrate formula (1) for $\eta(s)$ above seems to converge for $\Re(s)>-m$ as $N\to\infty$ when evaluated with $m\in\{1,2,3,4\}$. In the following figures formula (1) is evaluated with upper limits $N=100$, $N=101$, $N=1000$, and $N=1001$ in orange, green, red, and purple respectively overlaid on the blue reference function.

---

The red discrete dot at $s=-m$ visible in most of the figures below illustrates $\frac{1}{2}\left(\eta_{\,m,100}(-m)+\eta_{\,m,101}(-m)\right)$. I'll note that I believe $\frac{1}{2}\left(\eta_{\,m,N}(-m)+\eta_{\,m,N+1}(-m)\right)$ evaluates exactly to $\eta(-m)$ for all values of $N\ge 0$, and $\eta_{\,m,N}(-j)$ evaluates exactly to $\eta(-j)$ where $j\in \mathbb{Z}\land 0\le j<m$ for all values of $N\ge 0$.

---

This leads to the following representations for $\eta(-j)$ which I believe are valid for $j\in\mathbb{Z}\land j\geq 0$ where $\binom{a}{b}$ is the binomial coefficient and $(a)_k$ is the Pochhammer symbol.

**(3)** $\quad\eta(-j)=\frac{1}{2^{j+1}}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{j+1}(-1)^{n-1}\,n^j\sum\limits_{i=1}^{j+2-n}\binom{j+1}{j+2-n-i}\\$ $\qquad\qquad\quad\,\,=\frac{1}{2^{j+1}}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{j+1}(-1)^{n-1}\,n^j\binom{j+1}{j+1-n}\,_2F_1(1,n-j-1;n+1;-1)\\ $ $\qquad\qquad\quad\,\,=\frac{1}{2^{j+1}}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{j+1}(-1)^{n-1}\,n^j\binom{j+1}{j+1-n}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k(n-j-1)_k}{(n+1)_k}$

---

[image: Figure (1a)] [image: Figure (1b)]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of Formula (1) for $\eta(s)$ with $m=1$

---

[image: Figure (2a)] [image: Figure (2b)]

**Figure (2)**: Illustration of Formula (1) for $\eta(s)$ with $m=2$

---

[image: Figure (3a)] [image: Figure (3b)]

**Figure (3)**: Illustration of Formula (1) for $\eta(s)$ with $m=3$

---

[image: Figure (4a)] [image: Figure (4b)]

**Figure (4)**: Illustration of Formula (1) for $\eta(s)$ with $m=4$

---

The following table illustrates $f(m,n)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m-n+1}\binom{m}{m-n+1-i}$ for $m=1..n$ which seems to correlate to https://oeis.org/A104709.

---

$\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{n} & \text{f(m,n)} \\
 1 & \{1\} \\
 2 & \{3,1\} \\
 3 & \{7,4,1\} \\
 4 & \{15,11,5,1\} \\
 5 & \{31,26,16,6,1\} \\
 6 & \{63,57,42,22,7,1\} \\
 7 & \{127,120,99,64,29,8,1\} \\
 8 & \{255,247,219,163,93,37,9,1\} \\
 9 & \{511,502,466,382,256,130,46,10,1\} \\
 10 & \{1023,1013,968,848,638,386,176,56,11,1\} \\
\end{array}$

Comment: Forjmula (2) comes from [MSE question 3182855](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3182855) "Question on convergence of formula for Dirichlet eta function $\eta(s)$".